# How to get the ID of the most recently inserted Access record?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have pretty much mastered how to add, delete and modify records in Access from VB NET, but most of the "reading" is done via populating a grid view box and then double clicking that to edit the record.

This works for most cases, but I need to be able to capture the most recently added record ID (field is "Request ID") to a string after adding it.

The only way I can think to do this would be do do a [SELECT *] in the DataGridView to pull all the records, and then have .NET return me the highest number found in the gridview, but that seems pretty sloppy.

Is there an easier way to pull the most recent record direct from the database?

Comment: `that seems pretty sloppy` and unreliable on a multi user system

Comment: There is no @@Identify in MS ACCESS that works universally. It's only good for the current connection, so it's worthless.

Comment: Thanks Gord I will check that out